# Can a Windows Vista-PC access two different NFS/Samba - shared directories?

Tags: network-shares

a coworker tries to access our intern Samba server as well as some other shared directory of his former university (I don't know if it's a NFS or a Samba or something else). It seems that Windows can only save one user and one shared directory.
Am I right with that assumption?
If not, is there a way to save two shared directories on one PC?

Answer (score 1):

On a single Windows PC, you can normally make multiple concurrent drive mappings to multiple shares on multiple servers using multiple domains and userIDs.

You have to be careful to present the correct credentials to each server. Obviously this is more relevant when authentication is local to some servers which are not participating in domain authentication.

```
net use w: \\mainserver\share           (uses local/domain login userID)
net use x: \\otherserver\share /USER:otherdomain\otheruser /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Some details of error messages and a little info about server set-up would help people to answer your question.

Using the `net use` command in a command prompt window may make it easier to explore the issue and to cut&paste information into superuser.com.